Riemann-integrability of a piecewise function, similar to Thomae and Dirichlet functions
Consider function  $f $ defined on an interval  $[-1,1] $. Evaluate whether  $f $ is continuous, Riemann integrable and/or Newton integrable on the given interval.
$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x ,& x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 ,& \text{otherwise} \\
\end{matrix}\right. $

Continuity

I think that  $f $ is almost continuous on the given interval since the points of discontinuity are points from  $\mathbb{Q}$, which is a null set, thus by Lebesgue's theorem (A bounded function is Riemann integrable iff it's almost continuous) it should also indidicate a possible Riemann-integrability.

Newton-integrability

The function $f$ does not have the Darboux's property, thus $f$ does not have a primitive function and it is not Newton-integrable.
(using the theorem that says "If $f$ has a primitive function on interval $I$, then $f$ has the darboux property on interval $I$.")

Riemann-integrability

The truth is, I still struggle with understand why Riemann's function (Thomae function) is Riemann-integrable whereas Dirichlet's function isn't. I know the proof using the upper and lower sums that show that Dirichlet's function isn't Riemann integrable ... by why can we use the argument that "$\mathbb{Q}$ form a null set and according to Lebesgue's theorem, the function is Riemann integrable$  for Thomae function but it doesn't work with Dirichlet's function?
That's also why I'm struggling to figure out whether I can or cannot use this argument for my function $f$.

That function is actually discontinuous at every point other than $0$.

@JoséCarlosSantos how come?

For instance, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(1+\frac\pi n\right)=0\ne f(1)$.
